# Testing JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

JSON newbie trying to get a grasp on this. My page is not alerting anything. What is wrong here?

The name of this page is test.php.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>test</TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


</HEAD>

<?php 

 $arr = array ('item1'=>"test1",'item2'=>"test2",'item3'=>"test3");      
 $test = json_encode($arr);
 echo $test;

?>
```

```
$(function() { 
   $.getJSON('test.php',function(data) {   

    alert("Testing Data Item1 , its value is: >" + data.item1 + "<"); 

           $.each(data,function(i, item) {     
    alert(item.key);       
            });    
        }); 
    });  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the HTML from the page outputting the JSON. All you want in `test.php` is:

```
<?php 
 $arr = array ('item1'=>"test1",'item2'=>"test2",'item3'=>"test3");      
 $test = json_encode($arr);
 echo $test;
?>
```

The one thing i usually do though is also explicitly set the content type header:

```
<?php 
 header('Content-type: application/json');
 $arr = array ('item1'=>"test1",'item2'=>"test2",'item3'=>"test3");      
 $test = json_encode($arr);
 echo $test;

?>
```

Comment: OK. I separated the PHP from the HTML and including the HTML into the PHP. Made your suggestions but still no response.

Comment: Did you try examining the response with firebug, or accessing `test.php` firectly with the browser? If php is ouputting errors then it will invalidate your JSON.